How to run a workflow only when a push to main is made
I am very reluctant to post this question as it has been asked so many times before, however like so many people before me it really bugs why I can't make it work :-( ... Essentially I want to run a workflow in Github only when a push takes place in the main branch. This is what I started with:

name: main_workflow
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.event_name == 'push' && github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' }}
    steps:
       ...

Unfortunately that didn't work, in fact when I edit my .yml file on Github website and commit my change the action starts immediately. So after googling a bit more I replaced references of push  with    pull_request: and     if: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' }}
  I was a bit relieved to notice the action didn't fire after I saved my changes, but as soon as I committed a test change into another branch (not main) the action started again.
How can I achieve stopping all runs apart from pushing or merging into main?
Thinking in terms of coding I said to myself there must be a way to use an if: statement way at the top and just stop it there with an exit 0 but from what I read on the web workflows can't be stopped like that. What is more the if: statement should go into each and every step, which to me sounds excessive. Shouldn't that on push or on pull_request statement do that for me?
Thank you for taking the time to read this, I am new to Github actions.
Update 1:
I think I solved my problem, hoping I won't bite my lip typing this! While trying a few more merge attempts and after reading more on the web, I stumbled upon the advice of adding types [closed] or types: - closed like so:

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [ closed ]
    branches:
      - main

or

on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - closed
    branches:
      - main

with adjusting the if: statement as well to accommodate for closed requests like so:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.pull_request.merged == 'true' && github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' }}
    steps:

This had an effect somewhat, but it was negative as the workflow stopped running at all! So I piece-wise removed a few lines and ended up with my original solution stated at the top of this post. All of a sudden now it seems to work alright. When I commit a change to a branch other than main, the workflow doesn't run, which is correct. When I commit to main it runs, which is also correct.
Don't know how this happened but for now it appears to function as per the documentation.

You are using the trigger push filter correctly in the yml you provided. I would just double check you are not pushing to main inadvertently. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#using-filters

@TwoFingerRightClick thanks for your comment, how would that be happening? I am only pushing to another branch (let's call it firstbranch). Granted, firstbranch was created from main but it sits on its own and not getting merged into main. When I switch to main I can't see any of those changes, so I know firstbranch is isolated. Thank you.

The workflow push trigger is correct except that it does not filter on paths inside the repo. The issue may be something else.
However, it is not obvious what you are doing and what you seeing exactly. Please provide your actions and observations  step by step. Please send a screenshot of the workflow that is running on push.

@DeltaGeorge thank you for your time, I think it works fine now.

Glad it worked out.

Check in repo, if branch is named master instead of main. If so, you have to add the following trigger only:
name: main_workflow
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master


Thanks, the branch is called main, I thought about that too.
